# Get query values in Python Blueprint route

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Python Flask api using a Blueprint and I want to paginate the results on one route. If a user includes the query paramater "page=" I want to get that value. How would I do that?

In this example code:

```
@api.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def list_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return jsonify(users=[i.serialize() for i in users])
```

I'd be wanting to add an if page param. Thanks! I'm very new to Flask, just trying it tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do exactly, you can either use variables in the route or query parameters.

Flask's quickstart guide provides nice introduction to variables in the route [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).
For example, in your case, you would do something like this:

```py
@api.route('/users/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def list_users(page):
    users = User.query.all()
    print(page) # the page argument contains the integer passed in the URL.
    return jsonify(users=[i.serialize() for i in users])
```

The above would print 1 if a request was made to the `/users/1` endpoint. However, if you choose this approach, the client will always need to provide a value for the page (i.e. requests to the endpoint `/user` won't work unless you add another route to handle that endpoint).

On the other hand, query parameters lets you make the page parameter be optional using the same route. For query parameters, your client would make a request using the query format (e.g. `/users?page=1`). 
To use a query parameter, you would setup your code as follows:

```py
from flask import request

@api.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def list_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    page = request.args.get('page', None)
    if page is None:
        # the page parameter was not given in the request, handle it accordingly
    else:
        # page parameter was in the request, handle it accordingly
    return jsonify(users=[i.serialize() for i in users])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.